# Stepped into the kitchenette

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, colloquial-language

Can you use *into* (rather than *to*) when talking about a kitchenette—even though a kitchenette isn't a place that you *enter*?

Note: Google Ngrams says that "stepped into the kitchenette" is [way more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stepped%20to%20the%20kitchenette%2C%20stepped%20into%20the%20kitchenette&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstepped%20into%20the%20kitchenette%3B%2Cc0) than "stepped to the kitchenette."

[image]

Comment: Why do you think a [kitchenette](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kitchenette) isn't a place you can enter?  It's a room, or at least an area.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a misconception. You might want to open a new question about how you use "enter," because it seems there's a misunderstanding there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JeffreyCarney has pointed out, this is a matter of usage.

You normally **step in/into** a place or an area (or **step on/onto** it if it's sort of a raised platform or something not too big like someone's toe).

It doesn't have to be an enclosed space. You can draw a circle on the ground and step into it, for instance.

Here are some examples from different dictionaries:

> *She opened the door and stepped out into the sunshine.* (Oxford)
> *I stepped onto the platform and started to speak.* (Macmillan)